# How to keep current tab active after page refresh using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Hi I am tying to keep current tab active after page reload refresh but unfortunatly it's not working what's my mistake Does anyone know please help me thanks.

**HTML View**

```
<!-- Tabs navs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-5" id="ex1" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="ex1-tab-1" data-mdb-toggle="tab" href="#ex1-tabs-1" role="tab"
      aria-controls="ex1-tabs-1" aria-selected="true">Slots</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link " id="ex1-tab-2" data-mdb-toggle="tab" href="#ex1-tabs-2" role="tab"
      aria-controls="ex1-tabs-2" aria-selected="false">Booking List</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="ex1-tab-3" data-mdb-toggle="tab" href="#ex1-tabs-3" role="tab"
      aria-controls="ex1-tabs-3" aria-selected="false">Rooms</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- Tabs navs -->


  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-tabs-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-1">
     Tab one
  </div>

 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-tabs-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-2">
     Tab Two
 </div>

 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-tabs-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-3">
     Tab Three
 </div>
```

**Script**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('a[data-mdb-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {

        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#ex1 a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
 });
```

Comment: on page load, does the first tab dispatches the `show.bs.tab` event? If so, you are setting the localStorage value before checking if it's already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab-link').on('click', function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(this).attr('href'));
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if (activeTab) {
        $('#ex1 a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            
<!-- Tabs navs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-5" id="ex1" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link tab-link active" id="ex1-tab-1" data-mdb-toggle="tab" href="#ex1-tabs-1" role="tab" aria-controls="ex1-tabs-1" aria-selected="true">Slots</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link tab-link" id="ex1-tab-2" data-mdb-toggle="tab" href="#ex1-tabs-2" role="tab" aria-controls="ex1-tabs-2" aria-selected="false">Booking List</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link tab-link" id="ex1-tab-3" data-mdb-toggle="tab" href="#ex1-tabs-3" role="tab" aria-controls="ex1-tabs-3" aria-selected="false">Rooms</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- Tabs navs -->


<div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-tabs-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-1">
    Tab one
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-tabs-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-2">
    Tab Two
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-tabs-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-3">
    Tab Three
</div>
```

**Note:** localStorage is disabled on Stackoverflow, so please execute this snippet on your local environment.